# Caret Package: Access performance results from repeated-cv

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I am using the caret package in R to train a few supervised predictive models and I would like to assess their stability across repeated-CV, i.e. I want to get the performance results for each iteration of the CV for each fold.
In the postResample() function and from the output of the train() function, they provide the average performance result across each iteration per fold.
For example in this Naive-Bayes model 3-fold CV which is repeated 25x, I would like to see the results for each iteration (a total of 3* 25 = 75 performance results). This is the current output from the trained model which aggregates the repetitions for each fold.

[image]

Is there a way to specify this in the caret package? If so, how can it be implemented? If not, what other methods can be used to accomplish this task in a non-model specific way?

Comment: When I try NBFull$resample provides the cross-validation scores for each fold and each repeat. Can you provide a reproducible example please?

Comment: I found the error was because I had used create folds so I could use a stratified CV when instead I should have used createMultiFolds to specify the number of repeats. If createFolds is used even while traincontrol() specifies repeatedcv, the index argument overides this.